# Laravel Relations : Get Reviews and associated Users of a Product

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, relationship

I have **User**, **Review** and **Product** Models in my app.
The relations are:

> - User **hasMany** Reviews
> - Review **belongsTo** User
> - Product **hasMany** Reviews
> - Review **belongsTo** Product

My Table structure is

> Products table
>
> ```
> id | name | price
> ```
>
> Reviews Table
>
> ```
> id | review | rating | user_id | product_id
> ```
>
> Users Table
>
> ```
> id | name |   email | password
> ```

When a specific Product page is visited, I want to display all the reviews of that product along with the users who wrote these reviews. So I tried:

```
$product = Product::where('id','=',$id)->with('reviews')->with('users')->get();
```

Of course that didn't work because `Product` does not have any direct relation with the `Users`.
Then I tried [Has Many Through](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relation. In Product Model :

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\User', 'App\Review');
}
```

This requires a `product_id` column in `Reviews` table which is there.
It also expects a `review_id` column in `Users` table which is not there (and does not make sense to put it in there as a User can have many Reviews).

#### So what is the proper way of doing this ?

How do I get all the reviews of a specific Product along with the users who wrote those reviews ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can chain relations to eager load with a dot `.` like so:

```
$products = Product::where('id','=',$id)->with('reviews')->with('reviews.user')->get();
```

Or because `reviews.user` will require `reviews` to be loaded as well, you can also omit the `reviews`:

```
$products = Product::where('id','=',$id)->with('reviews.user')->get();
```

You can then simply access the user as you'd expect:

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
    foreach ($product->reviews as $review) {
        $user = $review->user;
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly. You can drop ´->with(''reviews')´ it will be loaded automatically anyway to reach the users table: ´$products = Product::where('id','=',$id)->with('reviews.user')->get();´

Answer (score 0):

I found this on the Laravel documentation. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

This should work if you apply lazy loading. However, with what you have, if you call **review->user->name**, you should be able to load the user info on demand.